# How do I send a specific json to this service stack request

Tags: c#, servicestack

How do I implement the method call to generate this request in `ServiceStack`?

```
[Route("/publishmanifest", "POST")]
public class PublishManifest: List<string>, IReturn<bool> {}
To accept requests like:

POST /getconsignments
[
    "ABC1234",
    "ABC5678",
    "ABC9122"
]
```

I tried something like:

```
    var client = new Client(new JsonServiceClient("www.website.com"));
    var result = client.PublishManifest(myconnotes.ConsignmentNumbers.ToArray());


    public class Client
    {
        private readonly ServiceClientBase _serviceClientBase;

        public Client(ServiceClientBase serviceClientBase)
        {           
            _serviceClientBase = serviceClientBase;
        }
        public bool PublishManifest(PublishManifest request)
        {
            var result = _serviceClientBase.Post(request.ConsignmentNumbers.ToArray());
            return result;
        }
    }
```

But this didn't work, how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call ServiceStack Services you just need to send its populated Request DTO, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://www.website.com");
var request = new PublishManifest();
request.AddRange(myconnotes.ConsignmentNumbers.ToArray());
var response = client.Post(request);
```